# Representing Geoserver's WMS-T as time-aware KML for GoogleEarth frontend

Tags: geoserver, wms, kml, time

I'm using Geoserver to publish* sets of hourly raster imagery and fought for a while to get a working example of Time Aware KML accessing my Geoserver to enable GoogleEarth as a frontend.

A snippet of my KML is below:

```
<Folder>
    <NetworkLink>
      <name>inun_elev_20060829T010000</name>
      <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2006-08-29T00:30:00Z</begin>
        <end>2006-08-29T01:30:00Z</end>
      </TimeSpan>
      <Link>
    <href>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/drf/wms/kml?TIME=2006-08-29T00:30:00Z/2006-08-29T01:30:00Z&amp;layers=drf:Ernesto2006&amp;styles=Inundation6m</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
    <NetworkLink>
      <name>inun_elev_20060829T020000</name>
      <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2006-08-29T01:30:00Z</begin>
        <end>2006-08-29T02:30:00Z</end>
      </TimeSpan>
      <Link>
    <href>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/drf/wms/kml?TIME=2006-08-29T01:30:00Z/2006-08-29T02:30:00Z&amp;layers=drf:Ernesto2006&amp;styles=Inundation6m</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
...
```

I made use of information from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111966/kml-google-earth-big-complex-overlay-with-timeline-selector to get the time-aware backend working.  Also, the suggestion from http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/googleearth/tutorials/kmlplacemark/index.html#wms-demo-example of accessing the Geoserver's output as:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=tiger:poi
```

...was very helpful.  I had initially approached it as a NetworkLink to a WMS service in GoogleEarth, but that over-complicated things to the point of not working.  Using the Geoserver-suggested KML links was much better than the URLs I found from point GE at a WMS.

For standard WMS-T, I inserted the TIME=timespan in the query strings per the above snippet, and corresponding KML:TimeSpan and it works.

I'm currently generating this KML file using a perl script, but I wonder if there are other/more-standard tools for generating time-aware KML from a time-aware WMS-T service?

(*) My data is currently private, but a publicly available sample WMS-T capable service is http://ecowatch.ncddc.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/ncom_amseas_agg/AmSeas_Apr_05_2013_to_Current_best.ncd?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: QGIS can work as a WMS-T frontend with the TimeManager plugin: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34667/does-qgis-have-wms-t-wms-with-time-support  but it looks like GoogleEarth needs an external program to write time-aware KML for it.

Comment: ArcGIS seems to have a couple methods of dealing with WMS-T:  https://github.com/Esri/WMSMultiDimensionalEsriViewer  and http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/31/creating-a-time-enabled-wms-with-arcgis-server-10/ (see the 'Consuming the time-enabled WMS' section)

Comment: The time template thing at http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/google_earth/time.html is intriguing.  Does this mean that one can put a time.ftl template file in the data directory and time-aware KML will be generated automatically?