# How to specify TIME parameter in URL for WMS-T server in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, wms-time

Does anyone know how to specify the time parameter for accessing data through a WMS-T server in QGIS?

I am trying to access fire data from FIRMS web server :(https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/web-services/#firms-wms-t)

The WMS-T GetCapabilities url is:
https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms-t/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GETCAPABILITIES

How do I add the TIME parameter so that I can access the fire hotspots layers for specific dates?

Comment: example http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r-t.cgi?LAYERS=nexrad-n0r-wmst&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TIME=2005-08-29T14%3A00%3A00&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-90,22.5,-78.75,33.75&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256 [TIME=2005-08-29T14%3A00%3A00]

Comment: See TimeManager Plugin QGIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34667/does-qgis-have-wms-t-wms-with-time-support/153709#153709

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw the other post already, but can't figure out how to adjust it for my specific example...