# Failing add WMS basemap

Tags: wms, error, basemap

Here in the south of France are some huge fires running ... I wanted to create a map of them by adding data from a WMS I thought usefull : http://effis.jrc.ec.europa.eu/applications/data-and-services/

But when trying to add one of the WMS provided urls to my base map, it fails ...

Example : http://ies-ows.jrc.ec.europa.eu/effis?LAYERS=modis.hs&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SINGLETILE=false&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-35.0,25.0,50.0,72.0&WIDTH=596&HEIGHT=330&TIME=2017-07-19/2017-07-26

displays the error message :

> The URL is either invalid or contains unsupported projections

Any ideas of how I can use these data please ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what GIS application are you trying to add the WMS in?

Comment: What projections are listed in the getcapabilities response?

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below, I thought I was on a Carto.com forum (as It redirects me here). If you know this online tool and how to add my WMS (http://ies-ows.jrc.ec.europa.eu/effis), I will be glad to you ! By the way, I continue using QGIS, but Carto.com offers publish capabilities I found helpful ! See you !

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to view in QGIS, I was able to view that WMS in QGIS 2.18.11 using the TimeManager plugin as described in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/how-to-specify-time-parameter-in-url-for-wms-t-server-in-qgis). 
I used http://ies-ows.jrc.ec.europa.eu/effis for the url of the WMS.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. I thought my question have been posted to a "Carto.com" related forum. That's where I get the error from.
But I thank you for the time manager plugin I didn't know and really helpful too ! 
See you !